# Delete page export in community

Tags: community, lightning-community

I have to make some structure changes to a community.
In order to do that and save time I need to export the Home page so I can reuse it when creating a new one from it, instead of rebuilding it manually.

When I am on the home page I go to Setting -> Developer -> Export a Page -> Select "Home" page -> click "Export" button
then I get

"To export your Experience Builder page, first resolve the following issues.
Error 1:
Home : The page has already been exported. Rename the page you're trying to export, or delete the previously exported page and try again."

[image]

That is true I already have page exported with the name Home.

[image]

I can not rename the "Home" page so my only option is to delete the previous export of that same page.

Do you know from where I can do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete an exported or imported page, from Setup, in the Quick Find box, enter Digital Experiences, and click Pages.

Comment: Thank you! That works much better than the workaround that I have found

Answer (score 1):

The good SF support people helped me on that:

You can do the re-naming or deletion using the Page Variation.
For example, if you open the Home Page , you can rename the Page variation temporarily  by clicking the dropdown option > Rename

The Name of the page will not be changed . No need to re-publish.
Then you will be able to export the page.
If you have a page variation , you can also use that , either delete and create a new page variation or delete the page variation.

After the export , you can change the name back.